# dc.js barChart bars overlapping

Tags: javascript, d3.js, visualization, data-visualization, dc.js

[image: the faulty graph]

This is my datetime barChart. When I use a fiddle (see [here](http://jsfiddle.net/6pwx6/2/)) to try and replicate the issue, it works as  intended.
NB : The data takes a while (~30sec) to load from github.

Here is the code for the graph :

```
    pnlPerDaybarChart
    .height(300)
    .width(700)
    .dimension(dims.date)
    .group(groups.date.pnlSum)
    .valueAccessor(function(d) {
        return Math.abs(d.value);
    })
    .renderTitle(false)
    .x(d3.time.scale().domain([minDate,maxDate]))
    .xUnits(d3.time.days)
    .colors(colorChoice)
    .colorAccessor(function(d) {
            if (+d.value>0) {
                return("positive");
            } else {
                return("negative");
            }
        })
    .brushOn(true)
    .elasticY(true)
    .margins({left: 70 ,top: 10, bottom: 30, right: 50})
    .centerBar(true);
```

Am I missing something obvious here ? If not, any ideas where I should start debugging ? I have spent a fair amount of time on this one and I can't find anything wrong.

EDIT: when I remove the `.xUnits` instructions, I get very skinny bars but well placed along the axis. That leads me to think that there is something wrong with the calculation of the width of the bars. I don't know how to debug that specific calculation though. If anyone knows, I'll be happy to dig into it.

EDIT2 : The `width` attribute of the `<g class="chart-body"><g class="stack _0"><rect class="bar"></rect></g></g>` elements within the `svg` are all set to a wrong value. If anyone could point me to where this is calculated in the `d3` library, I could maybe take it from there.

EDIT3: I found the source of my issue. The width of the bars is incorrect because when calculateBarWidth() has run once to instantiate the graph, it doesn't run anymore even when dc.redrawAll() is called. In my case I successively add chunks of records to my crossfilter and redraw the graphs. The new question is 'How do I force calculateBarWidth() to rerun ?'

Comment: What's  the difference between your non-working version and the working jsfiddle?

Comment: No differences. That's what's driving me mad. I have even made sure the sources are the same by redownloading them.

Comment: Could you maybe point me to where the `width` attribute of the `<g class="chart-body"><g class="stack _0"><rect class="bar"></rect></g></g>` is calulated so I can see where it goes wrong within d3 ?

Comment: Maybe it's some CSS that's missing?

Comment: @LarsKotthoff Thanks for the tip but same thing for the css : I pointed directly to the one used on the `dc.js` website...

Comment: @LarsKotthoff Do you happen to know which function calculates the width of the bars in `d3.js` ? I wasn't able to find it.

Comment: Well, something that sets the `width` attribute on a `rect` element.

Comment: Can you use firebug or some other debugger and try to see whats the width of each vertical bar. I ran into same issue sometime back but that was because I was wrongly setting xUnits .. which does not look like the case here .. and can you try setting xUnits to time.week ..just to see what it does

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
.on("preRedraw", function (chart) {
        chart.rescale();
    });
    chart.on("preRender", function (chart) {
        chart.rescale();
    });
```

The answer comes from [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/dc-js-user-group/Iih8FoDt4Pk).

Answer (score 2):

I think you are looking for barChart.calculateBarWidth.  (`src/bar-chart.js` if you're considering submitting a PR ;)

There have been other bugs reported against it recently to do with ordinal bar charts:

https://github.com/dc-js/dc.js/issues/533

I don't know if there is also a bug with dates.  It seems odd to me that the same code would work in a fiddle but not in your page... that's pretty rare.

Comment: I think I found the source of my issue. So the width of the bars is incorrect because when `calculateBarWidth()` has run once to instantiate the graph, it doesn't run anymore even when `dc.redrawAll()` is called. In my case I successively add chunks of records to my crossfilter and redraw the graphs. How do I force `calculateBarWidth()` to rerun ?

Comment: I think this may be a bug.  Does it get recalculated with renderAll?