# Bar overlapping in DC bar chart

Tags: javascript, d3.js, dc.js

I have a bar chart but each column is overlap like image below : 
[image: Overlap chart]

but when i create fiddle in [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MBehtemam/b36HT/) with copy and paste code the chart is not overlap. in my original page i have only styles from twitter bootstrap.even i remove any style in page i have overlap column in bar chart.
this is my code :

```
 var parseDate = d3.time.format("%Y/%m/%d").parse;
 var myData = [{
 seller: 'Ehtemam',
 sdate: '2014/10/09',
 unitprice: 10,
 quantity: 100
 }, {
 seller: 'Jafari',
 sdate: '2014/10/09',
 unitprice: 100,
 quantity: 106
 }, {
 seller: 'Jamali',
 sdate: '2014/09/09',
 unitprice: 105,
 quantity: 109
 }, {
 seller: 'Asghari',
 sdate: '2014/08/09',
 unitprice: 110,
 quantity: 106
 }, {
 seller: 'Rezaee',
 sdate: '2014/10/09',
 unitprice: 150,
 quantity: 107
 }, {
 seller: 'Akrami',
 sdate: '2014/08/09',
 unitprice: 1,
 quantity: 190
 }, {
 seller: 'Ehtemam',
 sdate: '2013/07/09',
 unitprice: 1,
 quantity: 180
 }, {
 seller: 'Ehtemam',
 sdate: '2014/06/09',
 unitprice: 12,
 quantity: 190
 }, {
 seller: 'Akrami',
 sdate: '2014/11/09',
 unitprice: 12,
 quantity: 150
 }, {
 seller: 'Ehtemam',
 sdate: '2014/12/09',
 unitprice: 14,
 quantity: 140
 }, {
 seller: 'Jafari',
 sdate: '2013/12/09',
 unitprice: 56,
 quantity: 130
 }, {
 seller: 'Asghari',
 sdate: '2014/12/09',
 unitprice: 33,
 quantity: 120
 }, {
 seller: 'Ehtemam',
 sdate: '2012/11/09',
 unitprice: 188,
 quantity: 10
 }, {
 seller: 'Rezaee',
 sdate: '2014/10/09',
 unitprice: 100,
 quantity: 10
 }, ];
 myData.forEach(function (d) {
 d.sdate = parseDate(d.sdate);
 d.year = d.sdate.getFullYear();
 });
 var data = crossfilter(myData);

 var sellers = [];
  for (var d in myData) {
 if (sellers.indexOf(myData[d].seller) == -1) {
     sellers.push(myData[d].seller);
 }
 }
  var colorScale = d3.scale.ordinal().range(['#DB0A5B', '#F62459', '#F1A9A0', '#2C3E50', '#26A65B', '#E87E04', '#D35400']);
  var sellerDimension = data.dimension(function (d) {
 return d.seller;
 });
 var sellerGroup = sellerDimension.group().reduceSum(function (d) {
 return d.quantity;
 });
 var sellerChart = dc.barChart('#chart');
  sellerChart.height(300)
 .width(600)
 .dimension(sellerDimension)
 .group(sellerGroup)
 .x(d3.scale.ordinal().domain(sellers))
 .xUnits(dc.units.ordinal)
 .xAxisLabel('Sellers')
 .yAxisLabel('Quantity')
 .xAxis().ticks(3);
  sellerChart.title(function (d) {
 return d.key + ' : ' + d.value;
 });

 dc.renderAll();
```

Comment: Your code appears truncated. But all you need to do is reduce the width of the bars so they're scaled to your chart width. So using something like: barwidth = (w - marginright - marginleft) / data.length  - 1.5;

Comment: Thanks for the fiddle - turning it into a test case now.

Answer (score 2):

The jsfiddle you referenced is using version 1.71.  I would bet that your real code uses the 2.x version.

I confirmed that v2.x has this issue at http://jsfiddle.net/djmartin_umich/6zrMc/.

```
   chart.height(300)
        .width(800)
        .dimension(countryDimension)
        .group(countryGroup)
        .x(d3.scale.ordinal().domain(countries))
        .xUnits(dc.units.ordinal)
        .xAxisLabel("MMbbl = one million barrels")
        .yAxisLabel("Reserves (MMbbl)")
        .elasticY(true)
        .xAxis().ticks(0);
```

This issue is discussed at length at https://github.com/dc-js/dc.js/issues/533, but the issue is not yet resolved. I have referenced this stackoverflow discussion as an issue comment.

Update: This issue is now fixed in the latest DC.js version.  The JSfiddle above uses the latest, so it shows the fix.  Nice work Gordon

Comment: Also perhaps https://github.com/dc-js/dc.js/issues/593, and see this question for a possible workaround: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22448822/dc-js-barchart-bars-overlapping. Hope to fix this soon!

Answer (score 1):

Use `.barPadding`.  It takes a number between 0 and 1 and applies d3's bar width allocation instead of the dc.js code, which is obviously buggy.

Now we just have to figure out how to deprecate `.gap`, which defaults to 2.

Comment: also put in a fix for the current behavior, but `barPadding` is better and will be the default behavior in a later version.